# How to go back in the previous page, upon tapping the phone's back button without showing any dialog?

Tags: flutter

// I already tried this but it wont work
return  WillPopScope(
onWillPop: ()  { Navigator.pop(context);

```
      },
  child: Scaffold(),
```

error:Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Future' doesn't allow null.

- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  onWillPop: ()  { Navigator.pop(context);

Comment: Why do you put scaffold inside a child?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a screen in the stack then tapping the android back bottom will automatically go to the previous screen. this is the android default behavior. you don't have to wrap with `WillPopScope`.

If you want to show some dialog or do something by tapping the back button then wrap with WillPopScope.

onWillpop is an async function, it requires a function with a return type `Future<bool>`.

If you want to disable the default behavior of the android back button then you can use this.

```
onWillPop: () async {
       // do something here
        return false;
      },
```

Otherwise,

```
onWillPop: () async {
       // do something here
        return true;
      },
```

Returning true will not disable the default behavior of the android back button.